# How do I change a right hand to left hand coordinate representation for a transformation matrix?

Tags: matrix, raytracing, coordinate-transformation

I'm trying to implement ambient lighting into a ray tracer I've built, however my own implementation is in a left-hand (y up, x right, z forward) coordinate system while the resources I use use a right-hand system

I've tried reading on several articles and posts here dealing with changing system coordinate handedness (for example negating the z component) but I'm unsure which aspects I would have to change within this source (just up to step 4, please ignore the monte carlo sampling part)

https://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-basic-rendering/global-illumination-path-tracing/global-illumination-path-tracing-practical-implementation

1. Are there any changes I would have to do to the spherical coordinates they give to fit into a left-hand coordinate system?
2. Are there any changes I need to make for the world space transformation matrix or is negating z enough? Or perhaps flip the cross product terms?

Answer (score 0):

I also work with a left-handed coordinate system. When reading OBJ files (which use a right-handed coordinate system) all I do is:

```
        // Flip z, since obj uses a right-handed coordinate system and Ether uses a left-handed
        // coordinate system
        positions_.push_back(Point3f{x,y,-z});
        
        ...

        // Flip z, since obj uses a right-handed coordinate system and Ether uses a left-handed
        // coordinate system
        normals_.push_back(Normal3f{x, y, -z});
```

That`s it